# regex don't match if 'A' or 'B' exist (before 'C')

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to make sure that neither substring A nor substring B exist, unless after a Substring C.
If substring C exists and A or B come after that it is okay. How can I get that?

I thought about using `r'^.*(?<!C:.*)A.*|B.*'` but that would check if they DO exist (I think).
And `r'^.*(?<!C:.*)!A.*|!B.*'` should be true if just one of A or B doesn't exist.

Is there a way to replace | with a logical AND? And would that do the trick or should I do something completely different?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Maybe just `^(?:[^A-C]*C.*|[^A-C]*)$`? If these are placeholders, `^(?:(?:(?!A|B|C).)*C.*|(?:(?!C).)*)$`

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/x3Dez7/2 and https://regex101.com/r/x3Dez7/3

Comment: They were placeholders, so second example worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @Dröömbüddel Could you confirm whether `AAABBB` should match or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should work:

```
import re

pattern = r'^((?!.*?(A|B))|(((?!A)(?!B).)*?C)).*$'

cases = ['xxx','A','B','xxxAxxx','xxxBxxx','xxCxxAxx',
         'xxCxxBxx','xxAxxCxxBxx', 'xxAxxCxxBxxCxx']
for s in cases:
    print(s,bool(re.match(pattern,s)))

xxx True
A False
B False
xxxAxxx False
xxxBxxx False
xxCxxAxx True
xxCxxBxx True
xxAxxCxxBxx False
xxAxxCxxBxxCxx False
```

- Everything is done in a lookahead that will inhibit the full string match if undesirable patterns are present
- There are two parts to the lookahead:
- The first part of the exclusion: `(?!.*?(A|B))` negatively matches any number of characters followed by A or B.  So the string is good when there are no A and no B in it (independently of any C being present)
- The second part of the exclusion: `(((?!A)(?!B).)*?C)` finds the first instance of C after a repeating sequence of neither A nor B characters.  So, if there are any A or B (i.e. passed first exclusion), only a C preceding them all will allow the string to match.
- Either of these two lookahead expression represent a valid string  but at least one of the two must match otherwise the full match will not happen
- The rest of the expression `^`...`.*$` is merely matching the whole string when either conditions is met.

Comment: hm, your example stops working once the regex is applied the way I do in the rest of the code (the last case becomes True for some reason): 
`import regex as re     
re.DEFAULT_VERSION=re.VERSION1 
def regex_contains(s, rx):          
    return bool(rx.search(s))   

pattern = re.compile(r'^(?!.*?(A|B))|(((?!A)(?!B).)*?C).*$')  
cases = ['xxx', 'A', 'B','xxxAxxx', 'xxxBxxx', 'xxCxxAxx', 'xxCxxBxx', 'xxAxxCxxBxx']  
for s in cases:     
    print(s,bool(regex_contains(s,pattern)))`

Comment: re.search behaves a little differently and exposed a flaw in my original pattern (which didn't matter for re.match).  I needed to enclose the excluding conditions in a group with extra parentheses:  `^((?!.*?(A|B))|(((?!A)(?!B).)*?C)).*$` .  I fixed it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since `A`, `B` and `C` can be any specific text/pattern, you can use

```
^(?:(?:(?!A|B|C).)*C.*|(?:(?!A|B|C).)*)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PblI81/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of the string
- `(?:` - start of outer grouping:

  - `(?:(?!A|B|C).)*C.*` - any char, zero or more but as many as possible occurrences, that does not start `A`, `B` or `C` subpatterns, then a `C` pattern and then the rest of the line/string
  - `|` - or
  - `(?:(?!A|B|C).)*` - any char, zero or more but as many as possible occurrences, that does not start an `A`, `B` or `C` subpattern
- `)` - end of the outer grouping
- `$` - end of the string.

Comment: Doesn't this match `AAABBB` (i.e. no `C` to be found)? The second lookahead should be `(?!A|B)`.

Comment: @InSync From what I understand, there can be any A or B or other string if there is no `C`. [OP confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76975863/regex-dont-match-if-a-or-b-exist-before-c/76976417?noredirect=1#comment135698456_76975863).

Comment: I want NO match for: xxA|Bx or xxA|BxCxx or xxA|BxxCxA|Bx. I want to match xxxx or xxxxCxA|Bx. So really, there should be no A or B at all if there is no C - they may only appear after a C if there is a C. Sorry if my statement of the code working was incorrect! My sample size is a few thousand and I didn't find any errors upon rough inspection and the output seemed plausible. And I also struggle a lot with wrapping my head around regex :/

Comment: @Dröömbüddel Ok, so you just need to add `A|B` to the last negative lookahead.

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew Thank you, this also works! I accepted the other way as an answer just because I personally found the regex a little easier to understand :)